# ASP.NET Windows Authentication works with IP address in URL, but not dns

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I've set up an ASP.NET intranet website with

From another pc:
It works perfectly fine if I access it via IP e.g http://11.11.11.1:88/Default.aspx

Unfortunately, when I go to http://MyWebsite.mycompany.com:88/Default.aspx I get a login box popping up.

If I enter username/pass it just rejects it, and I can't get access

From the server:
Both IP and DNS alias work. So no problems while on the server itself

Anonymous user access is disabled

Any ideas?

Any suggestions on what further info I can give to help solve this?

**Additional:**

- Accessed via IE only (6 and up)
- I use IIS 6.0
- Username in Domain\Username format
- Config set to `<deny users="?">`
- AppPool identity as Domain\zWhatever (used for windows auth to sql db)
- AppPool identy user is in IIS_WPG group, plus is admin on server

Comment: have you tried COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME format instead of just username (where computer name is the computer in your intranet which you can connect from, NOT the computer you are trying to connect from)?

Comment: Worth a look: http://www.networksteve.com/forum/topic.php?TopicId=18587

Comment: can poyrazoğlu, I use Domain\Username

Comment: What auth type you use? Title says Win, but in description is Forms. What is correct?

Comment: Windows Auth. Where does it say I use Forms? I'll remove it

Comment: @mejobloggs, the first sentence says "ASP.NET forms", which I suppose is a little confusing. Just delete the word "forms", it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks was just trying to say I wasn't using MVC or anything. Have removed it

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716618/authentication-issue-with-an-intranet-website-running-under-iis6

Comment: @Tomas Voracek, thanks I'll check it out. Not sure what happens with duplicates but if an answer there works I'll paste it here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ohh riiight. Got it!

I changed my AuthenticationProvider for my website from "Negotiate, NTLM" to "NTLM, Negotiate"

Following these instructions:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215383

With a slight change to their instruction to set provider of course

mine:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/WebSite/root/NTAuthenticationProviders "**NTLM, Negotiate**"
```

You can get the Website ID by clicking on the "Web Sites" folder on the left in IIS. This should list all your website with their ID

Comment: That's odd. IIS 6 out of the box should work with ASP.NET Windows authentication. Had you changed this setting previously?

Comment: Never touched it before. I'm assuming it's just some weird combination of things that doesn't cause a problem in 99.9% of cases, but occasionally there's a snag

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that this was the solution for me as well with IIS 7.5.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Internet Explorer options, add `MyWebsite.mycompany.com` to your list of **Trusted Sites**.

In Internet Explorer:

- select "Tools"
- select "Internet Options"
- click the "Security" tab
- click the "Trust Sites" icon
- click the "Sites" button
- enter the website domain

  - e.g., `http://MyWebsite.mycompany.com:88` (use **https** if possible)
  - if the website doesn't have SSL, **un-check "Require server verification (https:)"**
- click the **Add** button (don't forget this part)

For Firefox, it's also pretty simple to [configure NTLM authentication](http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/).

For Chrome NTLM, see [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/61063/can-i-get-chrome-to-work-with-sites-that-use-windows-integrated-security).

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Note in Security/LocalIntranet, *.mycompany.com is present. So my website should automatically be a Local Intranet site